# How can i custom nextjs URL in production mode

Tags: routes, next.js

When i start my next project with npm run start for cart page i got http://localhost:3000/cart  but what i want is for the cart.js is to visit via http://localhost:3000/myprojectname/cart I try to use set in next.config.js with exportpathmap it works well in npm run dev but when i start program with npm run start it doesn't work as i expected how can i get URL path like this http://localhost:3000/myprojectname/cart instead of http://localhost:3000/cart for the cart page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wanna do is in you project's `pages` folder, you create a folder named `myprojectname`. Then inside the folder, move your cart.js.

What this does is it adds a `/myprojectname/` route to your URLs and to access the cart, you would have to access it like so: `/myprojectname/cart`

This is how NextJS does routing, based on how you structure your directories.

For more information, you can refer to this link: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages

Comment: So like you said. Either use NextJS routing structure or you can wrap it using for example nginx (I guess some revproxy) or maybe export project and serve it using Spring Boot (in which you could set up paths too)

Comment: @Shaq that's another way to do it. So many options, just have to choose the easiest one for you haha